# KeystoneJS: random string as default value

Tags: mongodb, keystonejs

I'm building a CRM with KeystoneJS. Part of the functionality are campaigns. Each campaign should have a unique identifier (apart from the lengthy mongodb _id), the campaign code.

In the KeystoneJS campaign model below, I'm generating a random string and set it as the default value for the campaignCode field.

This works, but unfortunately the campaignCode will always be the same randomstring (unleass I restart the server).

So the question is: how can I trigger the randomstring.generate() function each time a new campaign is created in the Admin-UI?

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var randomstring = require('randomstring');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;


var Campaigns = keystone.List('Campaigns',{
    map:{name:'campaignCode'}
});

Campaigns.add({
    campaignCode:{type:Types.Text,default: randomstring.generate(6)},
    subject:{type:Types.Text},
    body:{type:Types.Markdown,height:500}
});

Campaigns.track = true;
Campaigns.defaultSort = 'campaignCode';
Campaigns.defaultColumns = 'campaignCode,subject';
Campaigns.register();

Campaigns.register();
```

Answer (score 2):

I set the field without a default or initial value.

For me, I am setting an initial random password...

```
User.add({
    password: { type: Types.Password },
```

Then in a pre-save hook I generate a password.

```
User.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (!this.password) {
        this.password = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8)
        console.log(this.password);
    }
    next();
});
```

or use this.isNew

```
User.schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (this.isNew) {
        this.password = Math.random().toString(36).slice(-8)
        console.log(this.password);
    }
    next();
});
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for providing the "isNew" and "not set" variants.

Answer (score 0):

```
default: (function () {
        return function () {
            return randomstring.generate(6);
        }
    })()
```

The above change should work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I just tried that, but it didn't work. I can only assume that's because text fields cannot hold a function (which is pretty much the same as the original problem that I was having).

Answer (score 0):

just generate the randomstring first and use the var as your 'default' parameter value:

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var randomstring = require('randomstring');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var randoDefault=randomstring.generate(6);

var Campaigns = keystone.List('Campaigns',{
    map:{name:'campaignCode'}
});

Campaigns.add({
    campaignCode:{type:Types.Text,default: randoDefault},
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I've tried that as well and this doesn't solve the problem. The campaign code will always be the same random string.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
`var randoDefault = randomstring.generate(6);`

You could try
`var randoDefault = keystone.utils.randomString([6,24]);`

Comment: This seems to have the same result as some of the other comments. It generates the same random code unless you restart the server.